# How to count the number of bold words and italic words in a markdown syntax file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, markdown

I've read that bold and italic words can be represented in markdown language by ** **bold_text** ** and * italic_text *, respectively. To have a both bold and italic text at once, you can wrap the text with 4 asterisks for bold and 2 underscores for italic (or vice versa).

I would like to write a bash script which determines the number of bold words and italic words. I guess that this comes down to counting the number of double asterisks , single asterisks, double underscores and single underscores. My question is how to count the number of specific strings like "**" or "__" from a file, so I can know how many bold and italic words there are.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "No input file specified."
else 
    ls $1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && 
    echo $(cat $1 | grep -o '\<**>\' | wc -c) || echo "File $1 does not exist."
fi
```

Example input file:

```
**This is bold and _italic_** text.
```

Expected output:

```
Bold words: 5
Italic words: 1
Bold and italic words: 1
```

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Ok, I will add my script so far.

Comment: Add an example with multiple lines and your desired output for that sample to your question.

Comment: Added the example input and the expected output.

Comment: On the one hand, you say "my question is: how to count the number of `**` and `__` in a file" (not so hard), but on the other hand, your example input/ouput seem to expect a translation to the exact number of words enclosed between these (not so easy). Which is it?

Comment: I guess that if I count those numbers, then I can divide them by 2 to get the number of bold words and italic words. However I think that this won't work to get the both bold and italic words...

Comment: `**one two three**` has 4 `*`, but any number of words between them.

Comment: Also, you can use both `*word*` and `_word_` for italics. How do you tell `*one* *two*` (two words in italics) apart from `**one two**` (two words in bold)?

Comment: You are right, it seems that I have not thought enough about this problem. When I come upon the `**` sequence, should I start to count the words until I find another sequence of `**`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100856/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-polb).

Comment: Are the start- and end-tags of bold (and italic) always on the same line (line-parsing allowed) ? Or can a complete paragraph e bold with `**` on the first and after the last line ?

Comment: I would suggest you grab a copy of `pandoc` which is the defacto standard for parsing markdown and take the standard `writer` script (which is easy to read `lua` for which you don't need a compiler) and modify it to count bold and italic words... https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/sample.lua

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple approach

A few assumptions:

- Bold uses `__`, italic uses `*` (even though it might also be `**` and `_`)
- No "funny stuff" like (inline) code with these characters, or escaped `_` or `*`, or lists with leading `*` that throw our count off

Now, to count bold words, we can use

```
grep -Po '__.*?__' infile.md | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l
```

This looks for anything between two pairs of `__`. I used the Perl regex engine (`-P`) to enable non-greedy matching (`.*?`); otherwise, something like `__bold__ not bold __bold__` would be just one match. `-o` returns just the matches.

The second grep matches the words: any sequence of one or more non-space characters; and `wc -l` counts the lines of output.

The same works for italics:

```
grep -Po '\*.*?\*' infile.md | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l
```

To combine these (for bold *and* italic), the command lists have to be combined. For italic inside bold:

```
grep -Po '__.*?__' infile.md | grep -Po '\*.*?\*' | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l
```

and bold inside italic:

```
grep -Po '\*.*?\*' infile.md | grep -Po '__.*?__' | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l
```

#### Cleaning up a more realistic file

Now, a real markdown file might have a few extra surprises (see "Assumptions"):

```
* List item with **bold word**

Line with **bold words and \* an escaped asterisk**

Here is an *italicized* word

And *italics with a **bold** word inside*

And **bold words with *italics* inside**

    Code can have tons of *, ** and _ and we want to ignore them all

Also `inline code can have * and ** and _ to be ignored`, right?
```

which would render as

> - List item with **bold word**
>
> Line with **bold words and * an escaped asterisk**
>
> Here is an *italicized* word
>
> And *italics with a **bold** word inside*
>
> And **bold words with *italics* inside**
>
> ```
> Code can have tons of *, ** and _ and we want to ignore them all
> ```
>
> Also `inline code can have * and ** and _ to be ignored`, right?

One approach to clean up something like this up would be a sed script:

```
/^$/d                           # Delete empty lines
/^    /d                        # Delete code lines (start with four spaces)
s/`[^`]*`//g                    # Remove inline code
/^\* /s/^\* (.*)/\1/            # Remove asterisk from list items
s/\\\*//g                       # Remove escaped asterisks
s/\\_//g                        # Remove escaped underscores
s/`[^`]*`//g                    # Remove inline code
s/\*\*/__/g                     # Make sure bold uses underscores
s/(^|[^_])_([^_]|$)/\1\*\2/g    # Make sure italics use asterisks
```

with the following result:

```
$ sed -rf md.sed infile.md
List item with __bold word__
Line with __bold words and  an escaped asterisk__
Here is an *italicized* word
And *italics with a __bold__ word inside*
And __bold words with *italics* inside__
Also , right?
```

Ready for consumption by the commands from the first section.

#### Putting it all together

Everything together in a script that takes the markdown file name as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="$1"
tempfile="$(mktemp)"

sed -r '
    /^$/d
    /^    /d
    s/`[^`]*`//g
    /^\* /s/^\* (.*)/\1/
    s/\\\*//g
    s/\\_//g
    s/`[^`]*`//g
    s/\*\*/__/g
    s/(^|[^_])_([^_]|$)/\1\*\2/g
' "$fname" > "$tempfile"

bold=$(grep -Po '__.*?__' "$tempfile" | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l)
italic=$(grep -Po '\*.*?\*' "$tempfile" | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l)
both=$((
    $(grep -Po '__.*?__' "$tempfile" |
        grep -Po '\*.*?\*' | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l)
    +
    $(grep -Po '\*.*?\*' "$tempfile" |
        grep -Po '__.*?__' | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | wc -l)
))

rm -f "$tempfile"

echo "Bold words: $bold"
echo "Italic words: $italic"
echo "Bold and italic words: $both"
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$ ./wordcount infile.md
Bold words: 14
Italic words: 8
Bold and italic words: 2
```

#### Shortcomings

- This can be tripped up by words containing underscores. Some markdown flavours ignore these and assume they're part of the word.
- I'm sure I missed a few edge cases in the cleanup

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to change the ** to another thing to make the problem easier.
I choosed ~, you can replace it to something else

```
$ cat test
**bold**
*italic*
**bold**

sed 's/\*\*/~/g' test
~bold~
*italic*
~bold~
```

Now for bold ones you should count the number of ~ and finally divide it by 2
count the number of ~

```
$ cat test | tr -d -c '~'
~~~~
$ cat test | tr -d -c '~' | wc -c
4
```

now divide it by 2, first save the output in a variable.

```
$ bold=`cat test | tr -d -c '~' | wc -c`
$ expr $bold / 2
2
```

Do the similar things for the italic one.